# Save image to user machine

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to do something like Facebook's "Download" Photo link when viewing an album photo. Trying to avoid opening popups.
Any Javascript/jQuery/PHP method to do it?
I am aware of this: http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html
But I don't have control over the server configuration to do so.
Please let me know what is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the header function of PHP to set the Content-Disposition header, for example:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Accept-Ranges: none");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);

echo $data;
```

Comment: This does not seem to accept range requests so this code is actually flawed.

Comment: But how am I supposed to do this if a user ALREADY rendered the page and HTML is already is shown?! My understanding is that I can't change the headers once that is done, even if i hold the object till the end of reading the PHP page, that doesn't solve it; the user will click the button to download the file only after the page is fully rendered. I think the solution should be Javascript/jQuery, not PHP.

Comment: @Emil: You're right, shouldn't have just copy-pasted code without looking at the context. I corrected it in the answer.

Comment: @johnshaddad: If you send a user to a download link, the page won't change, only the download dialog will appear. So for example, if a user clicks on a link to download.php, he will download the file/data without losing the current page (where download.php starts a download using these headers).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to access the server configuration. Just use [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)—before any HTML output.

Example:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a Content-Disposition [header](http://php.net/header) using PHP. No need to change the server configuration. So maybe something like this:

```
<?php
$file = 'folder/file.jpg';
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: But how am I supposed to do this if a user ALREADY rendered the page and HTML is already is shown?! My understanding is that I can't change the headers once that is done, even if i hold the object till the end of reading the PHP page, that doesn't solve it; the user will click the button to download the file only after the page is fully rendered. I think the solution should be Javascript/jQuery, not PHP.